# PHP How to delete an empty line of null variable or add backspace to it echo html text output

Tags: php, html, text, null, echo

How i can delete the empty line of null variable ?

for example

```
$line1 = "Hello All";
$line2 = "Hello You";
$line3 = "Hello Me";

$line2 = null;

Now when i echo 

echo "$line1<br>$line2<br>$line3";

it show empty line in the middle when i set variable to null value, 
So how i can delete this line ? 
i mean i don't want to show empty line. if variable value goes to null

Can i have to make $line2 = null; and then $line2 = something like backspace ?
```

How i can delete empty line of null variable ?

You help will be appreciated!

Note: i don't want to edit in last echo html line so you must have do anything before echo. i mean like set value of $line to backspace or any other solution.

i don't have permission to edit last echo line so do anything before echo statement.

```
 echo "$line1<br>$line2<br>$line3";  <== i don't have permission 
 to change a single letter in this line 
 So please make solution before echo line
```

Comment: Why would you like to set a variable to null and then delete it? Just set it to another value anyway...

Comment: @LelioFaieta I guess that was just to show the problem. It happens all the time during practical projects, especially with full names etc.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$line1 = "Hello All";
$line2 = "Hello You";
$line3 = "Hello Me";
$line2 = null;

if(!$line2) {
    $line1 .= '<del style="display:none">';
    $line3 = '</del><br>' . $line3;
}

echo "$line1<br>$line2<br>$line3";
```

Comment: Please read the question again, i don't want to edit echo line, all i have to do is before echo statement. you must have to set something for $line2 variable so when it will echo it should not show empty line

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is check if the variable is null.

```
if (!is_null($line1)) {
    echo $line1 . '<br>';
}
//repeat
```

Comment: if you don't want to change the echo line, which sounds ridiculous, you can use if (is_null($line2)) { $line2 = $line3; $line3=null;}

Answer (score 0):

Or do this?

```
$line1 = "Hello All";
$line2 = "Hello You";
$line3 = "Hello Me";

$line2 = null;
```

and when printing:

```
$output = "$line1<br>$line2<br>$line3";
echo str_replace('<br><br>' , '<br>' , $output );
```

Comment: it not solve the problem because i don't want to store all output text into another variable, i want to make solution before echo statement

Comment: in that case you would need to check for empty like Vasil suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
$line1 = "Hello All";
$line2 = "Hello You";
$line3 = "Hello Me";

$line2 = null;

$array = array($line1,$line2,$line3);
$array = array_filter($array);
foreach($array as $line){
  echo $line.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: it not solve the problem, do not store all variables in to array or any other variable because i don't want to edit last echo line , i must have to echo "$line1<br>$line2<br>$line3";

Comment: Is it static? If so you can simply do it like this: '$line1 = "Hello All";
$line2 = "Hello You";
$line3 = "Hello Me";

$line1 = $line1."<br>";
$line2 = null;
$line3 = $line3."<br>";

echo $line1.$line2.$line3;'

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11432411)